# Range.Find - trouble with .Found in wdInFieldResult

Tags: vba, ms-word

Acronym Search

When findRng.Find successfully discovers the search text within a field result (such as Table of Contents) the next .Execute begins at the start of the TOC rather than at the start position that had been set further down the document from the previous findRng.Find. This can be visually shown by choosing findRng.select. Per the findRng's Start and End properties, the selection should not include the start of the TOC, but it does AND this appears to be what the .Find method is also using because it becomes an Apple Corporate Headquarters address; i.e., One Infinite Loop. ;)

You can Watch the values of findRng.Start and .End which are as expected up until the .Execute statement near the bottom of the subroutine.

Unless anyone can fix the range reset issue I'd be happy just finding a way to quickly determine the .End location of the field that triggers wdInFieldResult yielding True and moving on with life.

```vba
Sub findAcronyms()
         Dim findRng As Range, tempRng As Range
         Dim oFld As Field
         Dim findStr As String, acroStr As String
         Dim acroTbl As Table
      '################# test code
         Dim testMode As Boolean
         Dim testIdx As Long, testSize As Long, i As Long
         testMode = True
         testIdx = 0
         testSize = 25
         If testMode Then
            ThisDocument.ShowRevisions = True
            ThisDocument.TrackRevisions = True
         End If
         Quiet (Not testMode)
      '#################

      'set acroTbl to ThisDocument's Acronym table
         Set findRng = ThisDocument.Content
         findStr = "ACRONYMS"
         With findRng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Style = WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
            .Text = findStr
            .Forward = False
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .Execute
            If Not .Found Then
               MsgBox findStr & ": not found!", vbExclamation
               Stop
               Debug.Print "Debug the issue..."
            Else
               findRng.MoveStart wdTable
               findRng.Expand wdTable
               Set acroTbl = findRng.Tables(1)
            End If
         End With

      'find occurrences of "(" and if closing parens "(" is within 7 characters then add to end of Acronym table
         Set findRng = ThisDocument.Content
         findStr = "("
         With findRng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = findStr
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .Execute
            Do While .Found 'until Find finds other than itself or EOD
      '################# test code
            If testMode Then
               findRng.Select
               Debug.Print findRng.Start
               testIdx = testIdx + 1
               If testIdx > testSize Then
                  Stop 'and Debug if necessary
                  Exit Sub
               End If
            End If
      '################
               i = findRng.MoveEndUntil(")", 7)
               If i > 2 And Not findRng.Text Like Left(findStr & "#######", _
    Len(findRng.Text)) Then
                  'check for pre-existence of acronym before adding to table
                  Set tempRng = ThisDocument.Range(acroTbl.Columns(1).Cells(2).Range.Start, _
    acroTbl.Columns(1).Cells(acroTbl.Columns(1).Cells.Count).Range.End)
                  tempRng.Find.ClearFormatting
                  With tempRng.Find
                     .Text = Mid(findRng.Text, 2, i)
                     .Forward = True
                     .Wrap = wdFindStop
                     .Format = False
                     .MatchCase = False
                     .MatchWholeWord = True
                     .MatchWildcards = False
                     .MatchSoundsLike = False
                     .MatchAllWordForms = False
                     .Execute
                     If Not .Found Then 'proceed with adding new acronym to table
                        With acroTbl.Rows
                           .Add
                           With .Last
                              .Cells(1).Range.Text = Mid(findRng.Text, 2, i)
                              i = findRng.Start
                              findRng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                              findRng.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
                              findRng.MoveStart wdWord, _
    -.Cells(1).Range.Characters.Count
                              .Cells(2).Range.Text = Trim(findRng.Text)
                              findRng.Start = i + 1
      Debug.Print .Cells(1).Range.Text, .Cells(2).Range.Text
                           End With
                        End With
                     End If
                  End With
               Else: findRng.MoveStart wdWord 'skip over 2 letter acronyms
               End If
               If findRng.Information(wdInFieldResult) Then
                  findRng.MoveStart wdParagraph 'in lieu of a better solution I need to determine how to get out of the field result
               ElseIf findRng.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
                  If findRng.InRange(findRng.Tables(1).Range.Cells(findRng.Tables(1).Range.Cells.Count).Range) Then 'test if in last cell
                     findRng.Expand wdTable
                     findRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                  Else
                     findRng.MoveStart wdCell
                  End If
               Else
                  findRng.MoveStart wdWord
               End If
      '################# test code
               If testMode Then findRng.Select
      '################
               findRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
               findRng.End = ThisDocument.Content.End
               .Execute
            Loop
         End With
         Stop
      End Sub
```

Comment: Following further investigation using a recursion procedure wherein only a portion of the Field.Result would be fed back into the Sub also results in the same behavior. That is, that the entire Field.Result is re-processed from the beginning upon performing the .Execute statement. It is my opinion that the inclusion of field result information renders the .Find function as broken.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the broken behavior of Field.Result actually simplified the routine. Instead, employing Range.MoveStartUntil yielded more straightforward processing.

The findAcronyms routine searches thru ThisDocument.Content for each successive occurrence of open parens "(" until the end of document is reached. Upon finding an open parens, several filtering tests are run to eliminate undesirable results such as numeric strings and excessive acronym length (limited to 7 characters). If successful, the acronym is compared to the existing Acronym table for pre-existence before being appended with Track Changes enabled. Plural forms of acronyms (those with last character = "s") are reduced to singular form to again eliminate redundancies.

Finally, the newly appended acronyms are scrolled onto the screen and the User is prompted if they wish to accept and sort the table as is. This is followed by another prompt to perform a reverse check employing the checkAcronymUse routine. This Subr verifies whether each acronym in the table actually appears in the document. Useful when tailoring a document from an existing template with pre-populated Acronym table.

```
Option Explicit

Sub findAcronyms()
   Dim findRng As Range, tempRng As Range
   Dim findStr As String, acroStr As String
   Dim acroTbl As Table
   Dim sBool As Boolean
'################# test code
Dim testMode As Boolean
Dim testIdx As Long, testSize As Long, i As Long, j As Long
testMode = False
testIdx = 0
testSize = 100
Quiet (Not testMode)
'#################

'update all field codes and scroll to first occurrence of error
   i = ThisDocument.Content.Fields.Update
   If i > 0 Then
      ThisDocument.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView ThisDocument.Range(i)
      Stop 'and Debug as req'd
      Exit Sub
   End If

   'set acroTbl to ThisDocument's Acronym table
   Set findRng = ThisDocument.Content
   findStr = "ACRONYMS"
   With findRng.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Style = WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
      .Text = findStr
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .Forward = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .Execute
      If Not .Found Then
         MsgBox findStr & ": not found!", vbExclamation
         Debug.Print "Debug the issue..."
         Stop
      Else
         findRng.MoveStart wdTable
         findRng.Expand wdTable
         Set acroTbl = findRng.Tables(1)
      End If
   End With

'   Main Loop: find occurrences of "(" and if closing parens ")" is within 7 characters then add to end of Acronym table
   Set findRng = ThisDocument.Content
   findStr = "("

   With findRng
      While .MoveStartUntil(findStr) > 0
         sBool = False
'################# test code
If testMode Then
   .Select
   Debug.Print .Start
   testIdx = testIdx + 1
   If testIdx > testSize Then GoTo Finish
End If
'################
         Set tempRng = .Duplicate
         tempRng.End = .Start
         i = tempRng.MoveEndUntil(")", 7) 'returns # of chars moved plus 1
         If i > 3 Then 'filter out occurrences of single char parens; (?)
            acroStr = Mid(tempRng.Text, 2, i)
            If Right(acroStr, 1) = "s" Then
               sBool = True
               acroStr = Left(acroStr, Len(acroStr) - 1) 'exclude redundant plural form of acronym
            End If
            If Not acronymExists(acroTbl, acroStr) Then
               addAcronym acroTbl, findRng.Duplicate, acroStr
               If sBool Then 'remove plural "s" from acronym definition
                  With acroTbl.Rows.Last.Cells(2).Range
                     j = InStrRev(.Text, "s")
                     If j = Len(.Text) - 2 Then 'all cells contain two hidden characters after the end of text
                        ThisDocument.TrackRevisions = True
                        .Text = Mid(.Text, 1, j - 1)
                        ThisDocument.TrackRevisions = False
                     End If
                  End With
               End If
            End If
            .MoveStart wdCharacter, i
         Else: .MoveStart wdCharacter, 2
         End If
      Wend
   End With
Finish:
   ThisDocument.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView acroTbl.Range, False
   If MsgBox("Accept and Sort Acronym table edits?", 65572, "Accept?") = 6 Then
      With acroTbl
         .Sort ExcludeHeader:=True, FieldNumber:="Column 1", SortFieldType:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, SortOrder:=wdSortOrderAscending, CaseSensitive:=True, LanguageID:=wdEnglishUS
         .Range.Revisions.AcceptAll
      End With
   End If
   If MsgBox("Verify Acronym table?", 65572, "Verify?") = 6 Then checkAcronymUse
   Quiet (False)
End Sub

Sub checkAcronymUse()
   Dim Rng As Range, findRng As Range
   Dim srcDoc As Document
   Dim myTblStyl As Style
   Dim srcTbl As Table, tgtTbl As Table
   Dim myRow As row
   Dim r As Long
   Dim findStr As String, srcAddr As String, srcDocName As String
   Dim findBool As Boolean
'################# test code
Dim testMode As Boolean
Dim testSize As Long
testMode = False
testSize = 20
Quiet (Not testMode)
'#################

'set srcTbl to ThisDocument's Acronym table
   Set Rng = ThisDocument.Content
   findStr = "ACRONYMS"
   With Rng.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Style = WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
      .Text = findStr
      .Forward = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .Execute
      If Not .Found Then
         MsgBox findStr & ": not found!", vbExclamation
         Debug.Print "Debug the issue..."
         Stop
      Else
         Rng.MoveStart wdTable
         Rng.Expand wdTable
         Set tgtTbl = Rng.Tables(1)
      End If
   End With

   ThisDocument.ShowRevisions = True
   ThisDocument.TrackRevisions = True

   For Each myRow In tgtTbl.Rows
      With myRow
         If Not .HeadingFormat Then 'ignore column headings
            findStr = Left(.Cells(1).Range.Text, .Cells(1).Range.Characters.Count - 1)
            If Len(findStr) < 3 Then findStr = Left(.Cells(2).Range.Text, .Cells(2).Range.Characters.Count - 1)
               Set findRng = ThisDocument.Content
               findBool = False 'true if Find is outside of tgtTbl
               With findRng.Find
                  .ClearFormatting
                  .MatchCase = True
                  .MatchWholeWord = False
                  .Text = findStr
                  .Forward = True
                  .Wrap = wdFindStop
                  .Format = False
                  .Execute
                  Do While .Found 'until Find finds other than itself or EOD
                     If findRng.InRange(tgtTbl.Range) Then
                        findRng.Expand wdTable
                     Else
                        findBool = True
                        Exit Do
                     End If
                     findRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                     findRng.End = ThisDocument.Content.End
                     .Execute
                  Loop
               End With
'################# test code
If testMode And .Index > testSize Then Exit For
'################
            If Not findBool Then .Delete 'acronym not used; delete from table
         End If
      End With
   Next myRow
'#################
If testMode Then Stop
'################
   tgtTbl.Select
   ThisDocument.TrackRevisions = False
   Quiet (False)
End Sub

Function acronymExists(acroTbl As Table, str As String) As Boolean 'check for pre-existence of acronym to avoid duplication in acronym table
   Dim tempRng As Range

   If str Like Left("#######", Len(str)) Then 'filter out numerical strings
      acronymExists = True
   Else
      Set tempRng = ThisDocument.Range(acroTbl.Columns(1).Cells(2).Range.Start, acroTbl.Columns(1).Cells(acroTbl.Columns(1).Cells.Count).Range.End)
      tempRng.Find.ClearFormatting
      With tempRng.Find
         .Text = str
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindStop
         .Format = False
         .MatchCase = False
         .MatchWholeWord = True
         .MatchWildcards = False
         .MatchSoundsLike = False
         .MatchAllWordForms = False
         .Execute
         acronymExists = .Found
      End With
   End If
End Function

Sub addAcronym(acroTbl As Table, Rng As Range, str As String)
   Dim ctr As Integer

   ctr = Len(str)
   ThisDocument.ShowRevisions = True
   ThisDocument.TrackRevisions = True

   With acroTbl.Rows
      .Add
      With .Last
         .Cells(1).Range.Text = str
         Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
         'check words at, before, and just after ctr locations for simple correlation match to str
         If Left(Rng.Previous(wdWord, ctr), 1) = Left(str, 1) Then
            Rng.MoveStart wdWord, -ctr
         ElseIf Left(Rng.Previous(wdWord, ctr + 1), 1) = Left(str, 1) Then
            Rng.MoveStart wdWord, -ctr - 1
         ElseIf Left(Rng.Previous(wdWord, ctr - 1), 1) = Left(str, 1) Then
            Rng.MoveStart wdWord, -ctr + 1
         Else: Rng.MoveStart wdWord, -ctr 'default, grab preceding words matching length of str
         End If
         .Cells(2).Range.Text = Trim(Rng.Text)
      End With
   End With
   ThisDocument.TrackRevisions = False
End Sub

Sub Quiet(Optional bool As Boolean = True)
   bool = Not bool
   With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = bool
      .DisplayStatusBar = bool
   End With
End Sub
```